# How to derive the closed form of this gamma quotient?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, special-functions, gamma-function

Sorry for this very localized question. I am aware that there are myriads of algebraic gamma quotients of this kind around, but in fact I have never seen proofs involving more than the well-known reflection and multiplication formulae of the gamma function. Though something deeper is obviously needed here...

**How to prove this conjectured identity?** 
$$\boxed{\frac{ \Gamma(\frac{1 }{21})\Gamma(\frac{4 }{21})\Gamma(\frac{16 }{21})}
{ \Gamma(\frac{2 }{21})\Gamma(\frac{8 }{21})\Gamma(\frac{ 11}{21})}\stackrel{\color{red}?}=\sqrt[3\  \ ]{14+3\sqrt{21}}\ }$$
The minimal polynomial (all numerically found) is $x^6-28x^3+7=0$. With that many multiples of $7$ occurring everywhere, I'd guess that there must be a whole family of such identities. Though for the next gamma quotient in the row, which should be
$\frac{ \Gamma(\frac{1 }{85})\Gamma(\frac{4 }{85}) \Gamma(\frac{16 }{85})\Gamma(\frac{64 }{85})}
{ \Gamma(\frac{2 }{85})\Gamma(\frac{8 }{85})\Gamma(\frac{ 32}{85})\Gamma(\frac{ 43}{85})}  $, my computer can't find any algebraic form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been speculated that all such relations of gamma functions can be derived from **reflection identity** and **multiplication theorem**. Another example can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2804457).

For your special case, omitting the $\Gamma$ sign, we have
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{{\left( {\frac{1}{{21}}} \right)\left( {\frac{4}{{21}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{16}}{{21}}} \right)}}{{\left( {\frac{2}{{21}}} \right)\left( {\frac{8}{{21}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{11}}{{21}}} \right)}} &= \frac{{\left( {\frac{4}{{21}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{16}}{{21}}} \right)}}{{\left( {\frac{2}{{21}}} \right)\left( {\frac{8}{{21}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{11}}{{21}}} \right)}}{(2\pi )^3}{7^{1/2 - 1/3}}\frac{{\left( {\frac{1}{3}} \right)}}{{\left( {\frac{4}{{21}}} \right)\left( {\frac{1}{3}} \right)\left( {\frac{{10}}{{21}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{13}}{{21}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{16}}{{21}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{19}}{{21}}} \right)}} \\
 &= {(2\pi )^3}{7^{1/6}}\frac{1}{{\left( {\frac{2}{{21}}} \right)\left( {\frac{8}{{21}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{11}}{{21}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{10}}{{21}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{13}}{{21}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{19}}{{21}}} \right)}} \\
& = \frac{{{{(2\pi )}^3}{7^{1/6}}}}{{{\pi ^3}}}\sin \left( {\frac{{2\pi }}{{21}}} \right)\sin \left( {\frac{{8\pi }}{{21}}} \right)\sin \left( {\frac{{10\pi }}{{21}}} \right)\\
&= \sqrt[3\  \ ]{14+3\sqrt{21}} \end{aligned}$$
in the first step, I used $$\Gamma (x)\Gamma (x + \frac{1}{m}) \cdots \Gamma (x + \frac{m-1}{m}) = (2\pi )^{(m-1)/2}{m^{\frac{1}{2} - mx}}\Gamma (mx)$$
in the last step, it is a direct computation on minimal polynomial.

Comment: Yes indeed, I wouldn't even have tried to apply the multiplication formula here! Still thinking about this speculation...

Comment: Thanks also for the added link. But for$$\prod_{k=0}^5\frac{\Gamma(\frac{49^k \pmod {78}}{78})}{\Gamma(\frac{7\cdot49^k\pmod {78}}{78})}=
\frac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{78})\Gamma(\frac{25}{78})\Gamma(\frac{43}{78})\Gamma(\frac{49}{78})\Gamma(\frac{55}{78})\Gamma(\frac{61}{78})\stackrel?=2(2\pi)^3\sqrt[6]{13}}{\Gamma(\frac{7}{78})\Gamma(\frac{19}{78})\Gamma(\frac{31}{78})\Gamma(\frac{37}{78})\Gamma(\frac{67}{78})\Gamma(\frac{73}{78})\stackrel?=\frac12(2\pi)^3\sqrt[6]{13}}=4,$$all numerators are $\equiv1\pmod6$, so how could the reflection formula possibly be applied in a proof of that?

Comment: This is the same as above. For the numerator, apply multiplication theorem with $m=6$, you will get $$\frac{{\left( {\frac{1}{{13}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{25}}{{13}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{43}}{{13}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{49}}{{13}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{55}}{{13}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{61}}{{13}}} \right)}}{{30{\text{ gamma terms}}}}$$ six terms in the numerator annihilate each other via reflection, as well as $30$ terms in the denumerator.

Comment: I try to get it... Ok for the six terms in your numerator. Clever! But in the denominator, a $\frac{77}{78}$ (coming from $\frac{25}{78}$) will survive, likewise 5 other terms of the 30, viz. exactly those which are the reflections of the ones in the original numerator. (i.e. $\frac{78-25}{78}$ etc.) I saw this when I tried to find out why it should work here, while the N=85 one in my OP doesn't. Still mysterious...